# Как в modx через скрипт подгрузить содержимое чанка?

Tags: ajax, веб-программирование, modx

Пытаюсь подгрузить средствами ajax чанк. Знаю метод подгрузки на самописном сайте. Делаю так:

1. Создаю на сервере файл с кодом блока который нужно подгрузить в
   расширении .php, например **noindex.php**
2. Подключаю его в head конструкцией

   ```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#noindex").load("/noindex.php");
        });
        </script>
   ```
3. Вывожу в шаблоне пустым блоком c идентификатором

   ```
       <div id="noindex"></div>
   ```

Но на сколько знаю в modx так не сделать, так как там надо оперировать существующими элементами. К тому же при такой подгрузке не работает ничего, отображается либо имя сниппета, либо чанка. Подскажите пожалуйста, как возможно еще попробовать подгрузить такое содержимое (чанк), чтобы оно работало?

Comment: для того, чтобы выполнить запустить snippet или "распарсить" chunk нужно выполнять код в контексте CMS (то есть используя шаблоны) или подключать API (ядро CMS) непосредственно в файле. Надеюсь вы так и делаете.

Comment: @diproart не так, первый раз столкнулся с modx и его структурой, поэтому и задал здесь вопрос.

Comment: версия modx: revolution, evolution?

Comment: @diproart Evolution 1.0.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### простой вариант

в modx evolution можно создать страницу в дереве документов с "пустым шаблоном" и "вызвать на ней" чанк или сниппет, в ajax указать адрес этой страницы. И не забывать, что сниппеты MODX, как раз придуманы для исполнения php-кода в контексте CMS. В настройках страницы можно изменить `mime-type`, кеширование и т.д.

### другой вариант

И можно подключить ядро MODX Evolution в ваш php-файл и уже делать, что душа пожелает.

```
define('MODX_MANAGER_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/manager/');

require_once MODX_MANAGER_PATH.'includes/protect.inc.php';
require_once MODX_MANAGER_PATH.'includes/config.inc.php';
require_once MODX_MANAGER_PATH.'includes/document.parser.class.inc.php';

$modx = new DocumentParser;
$modx->loadExtension("ManagerAPI");
$modx->getSettings();

session_name($site_sessionname);
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['mgrValidated'])) die('not enough mana...');

// ваша логика

$output = $modx->runSnippet('ditto', array('... params ...');

...
```

Но это уже сложнее, да и нужно ли...

> **off topic**: MODX версией ниже 1.2.x обладает множеством уязвимостей и лучше рассмотреть возможность обновления или миграции на другую платформу. Теперь за [MODX Evolution осталось только сообщество](https://github.com/evolution-cms/).

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Сложность возникала, как оказалось из-за того, что не правильно в ajax указывал адрес ресурса, пытался по [[~id]] и выводило всю страницу целиком.